PyCharm: "Run File in Python Console" not producing any output for a program with command line arguments
The program I am running runs fine when just doing a standard run or debug, but when I try "Run File in Python Console" On pyCharm profressional, no output is given at all. If I do "execute cell in Console", then I get the following error output where arg1 and datadirectory are added via "parser.add_argument(...)".
usage: pydevconsole.py [-h] [--arg1 ARG1]
                       [--data_directory DATA_DIRECTORY]
pydevconsole.py: error: unrecognized arguments: --mode=client --host= ... --port=...

Note that I have these arguments set up in the Run configuration, and even if they weren't, default values are set such that it should still run even without input arguments being provided. What's going on here? I want to be able to run in Python Console because I like to see the variable explorer (similar to Spyder) from all the objects created in main.
As an additional aside, does doing "run file in Python console" run the most recent configuration (with the arguments specified), or just uses the default ones?
